# Unit Testing context manager

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the below class. How could I write a unit test for the load_config_from_yaml method? I have written unit tests before but never with a context manager involved (in the tested side).

```
import logging.config
import yaml

# Config for the root logger
class RootLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_logger = self.load_config_from_yaml()

    @staticmethod
    def load_config_from_yaml():
        """
        Fetch the config in the yaml file to set up the console and file handlers
        Returns:
            logger object
        """
        with open('mylogger_config.yml', 'r') as config_yaml:
            config = yaml.safe_load(config_yaml.read())
            logging.config.dictConfig(config)
            return logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This is mylogger_config.yaml:

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
  sampleLogger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

Comment: The context manager is basically just a nice way, to create the file reference and close it after use. As this specific context manager is a built-in I would not worry about it in the testing.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So, no unit testing would be required for this class?

Comment: What do you want to test there? You could mock the `open()` function and test that logger is configured as you wish, but I wouldn't write such a test, if something is wrong with the logging you will notice immediately and also logger configuration and format might change.
But I would point out that you have hard-coded the config file name, which might not be the best design choice.

Comment: I would argue that the things that could go wrong that lie within your implementation (not built-in or other packages) are: 1. not exisiting file at the hard-coded location ('mylogger_config.yml') and 2. the dictionary lookup with the special `__name__` .  But the functionality of the context manager does not need any testing from your side.

Comment: @FlorinC. thanks so much for your input. How could I fix my design in order to avoid the hardcoded file name? Where could I fetch the name from?

Comment: @JonathanWeine thanks again for your input. 1. How could I write a test for checking if the desired file is at the location? 2. I thought the __name__ was a python convention for naming loggers. How could I fix that?

Comment: An easy way would be to have it as a parameter to that static method and move the hard-coded filename somewhere close in application initialization, but a more flexible way could be to read that setting from a project setting file or an environment variable.
Even though it doesn't sound like much, it will allow you to change which configuration you use for each environment, think about unit tests or CI/CD systems or develop/staging environments etc.

Comment: Picking up on Florins comment: hard-coding file names is often times not the best choice. If you rely on a set of resource files, you could define project wide constants for the paths. Testing if the files are present is not in the scope of unit testing this class, but you would rather set up a test that checks all necessary resource files. This very dependent on how your project looks like.

Comment: The plain "__name__" special is not bound to the class but depends on the role and name of the file that the class is implemented in. here is the [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/name-a-special-variable-in-python) for more details. Using this for a dictionary lookup seems very questionable to me

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. Much appreciated!